# How to calculate this divergence on manifold？

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a compact orientanble Riem manifold, $S^n$ be the standard n-sphere. $F:S^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function on $S^n$, $\nu:M\longrightarrow S^n$ be the Gauss map. Suppose $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection on $M$ with respect to $g$, and $\nabla^{S}$ denotes the Levi-Civita connection on $S^n$ with respect to the standard metric. Also we have the second fundamental form of $M$, write as $h_{ij}$.

**Goal:**  Calculate $div((\nabla^{S}F)\circ \nu) $

**My work:** Take local coordinates $\{e_i\}$ on $S^n$, and then $\{E_{i}:=e_{i}\circ \nu\}$ are local coordinates on $M$. Suppose $\nabla^{S}F=F^{i}e_i$, then we have $(\nabla^{S}F)\circ \nu=(F^{i}\circ \nu)E_i$. So the divergence can be calculated as follows:
$$div((\nabla^{S}F)\circ \nu )=(F^{i}\circ\nu)_{,i}$$

**Confusion**: I am stucked here since I have no idea about how to calculate the covariant derivative of a function composed with a map. And how can I get $h_{ij}$ in the final result? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Isn't $\nabla F$ just the same as $dF$? For rank 0 tensors, I thought that was the only thing you could do. But now I am confused as to why you would need to introduce $\nabla^S$ at all then.

Comment: @Keshav I mean that is gradient of F on S^n.

Comment: The gradient has nothing to do with the covariant derivative. The derivative of $\nu$ will be in terms of $h_{ij}$.